# Automating Tasks in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I am trying to find a way that will cause TFS to automatically create a second task when another task has been completed. The idea here is that once a developer has completed a task and moved it to the done column a 2nd task is created off the first one for the QA/QC members to start looking at the code and doing what they need to do.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in feature, but there are tools, many open source, that can help you implement your request.
One is [TFS Aggregator](https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator/): I am part of the core team, always looking for new contributors.

Comment: Thank you for the information Giulio it confirms the research I have been able to do. I will look at TFS Aggregator and see how it fits in with our current infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

This should be managed via your user stories, either via having a task for testing that can be grabbed by the QA team once the user story is ready for QA, or by defining a board column for the user story to indicate that it's development-complete and ready for QA.

Once a user story starts development, you shouldn't be adding tasks to it. Each task should be defined and estimated prior to the sprint starting for capacity planning purposes.

Comment: Maybe the OP is not using Scrum, so her/his request make sense